# Adding a background color to Cell OpenPyXL

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to make it where my code gives off a Green background on cell when it is "Present" and a Red background on cell if it is "Absent". Here is my code.

```
ws1.cell(column=1, row=t, value="%s" % blue_student_list)
if (student_check(i)):
    ws1.cell(column=2, row=t, value="%s" % "Present")
else:
    ws1.cell(column=2, row=t, value="%s" % "Absent")
```

This code works flawlessly, I'm just wondering how I can add in the background color behind the cell.

Comment: See [Conditional Formatting](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/formatting.html) in the openpyxl docs.

Comment: Just a 2 cents comment: the last 4 lines could be simplified into: `ws1.cell(column=2, row=t, value="Present" if student_check(i) else "Absent")`, using a `value1 if cond else value2` and no need to do `"%s" % "a string"`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html#styling-merged-cells):

```
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
        
sheet['A1'].fill = PatternFill(bgColor="FFC7CE", fill_type = "solid")
```

Comment: for me `bgColor` didn't work, but `start_color` and no `end_color` worked

Answer (score 42):

With `openpyxl 2.5.3`, the code above does not work.

after trying, following code worked:

```
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
sheet['A1'].fill = PatternFill(start_color="FFC7CE", end_color="FFC7CE", fill_type = "solid")
```

Comment: In my case, the `end_color` was not useful. It's probably used only when you define a gradient. You can also use `fgColor` (which happens to be shorter so easier to stick to shorter lines of code).

Comment: Could this also be applied to adding transparency to a chart?

Answer (score 17):

As @Charlie Clark (co-author of **openpyxl**) suggests, Conditional formatting might be a better way to go. More information in the [official doc](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/formatting.html)

If you want to change the background color, from more recent versions  keyword `bgcolor` seems to not work (in my case, the color of the cell ends up black).

Instead, you can use `start_color` or `fgColor`. For example, both solutions work:

```py
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
from openpyxl.styles.colors import BLUE

sheet['A1'].fill = PatternFill(start_color="000000FF", fill_type = "solid")
sheet['A1'].fill = PatternFill(fgColor=BLUE, fill_type = "solid")
```

If you want to use conditional formatting, this is an example on how to do (where strangely `bgColor` seems to work while `fgColor` does not):

```
from openpyxl.styles.colors import BLUE
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import FormulaRule


text_2_color = {
    "Present": PatternFill(bgColor="006C00"),  # Dark Green
    "Absent": PatternFill(bgColor="00FF0000"),  # Red
}
for text, color in text_2_color.items():
    ws.conditional_formatting.add(
        "A1:E1000",
        FormulaRule(formula=[f'A1="{text}"'], stopIfTrue=True, fill=color),
    )
```

Comment: From the [code](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/blob/branch/3.0/openpyxl/styles/colors.py) it seems YELLOW is currently disabled as a shortcut constant

Comment: Indeed, you can use RGBA color strings instead.

Comment: @mapto: changed color to `BLUE`

Answer (score 4):

**This is for openpyxl V 2.6 and above**

```
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

for col_range in range(1, 12):
    cell_title = sheet.cell(1, col_range)
    cell_title.fill = PatternFill(start_color="8a2be2", end_color="8a2be2", fill_type="solid")
```

*This will colour the cells from A1 to K1*

Answer (score 1):

I had great difficulty copying the background color of cells (from a tab in one book to a tab in another...)

After a lot of attempted workarounds, I found this to work:

```
 from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
 from openpyxl.styles.colors import COLOR_INDEX
 from copy import copy as shallow_copy, deepcopy as deep_copy
 # .
 # .
 # .
 if from_cell.has_style:
    if isinstance(from_cell.fill.start_color.index, int):
       start_color=COLOR_INDEX[from_cell.fill.start_color.index]

    else: # _sometimes_ a string...
          start_color=from_cell.fill.start_color.index

    end_color=start_color
    to_cell.fill=shallow_copy(PatternFill(fill_type=from_cell.fill.fill_type,
                                          start_color=start_color,
                                          end_color=end_color,
                                          patternType=from_cell.fill.patternType
                                 )
                     )
```

---

FYI: openpyxl is a great product; I don't think many developers realize what's possible using it. I will be supporting the project.

I think perhaps a number of developers mistakenly think it's anti-open source; but xlsx documents ARE also rendered by LibreOffice...