# How to color only sepcific headers in a dataframe and save it to excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl, styleframe

Let say I have dataframe like this:

```
     col1    sub col 2     col3       col4
0    A        A_1          pass        2
1    A        A_2          pass        4
2    A        A_1          fail        4
3    A        A_1          fail        5
4    A        A_1          pass        3
5    A        A_2          fail        2
```

I want to change the color of the header "sub col 2" to yellow, then save it as an excel file and have an output excel file like this one when I open the file?

[image: Output]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a background color to Cell OpenPyXL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35918504/adding-a-background-color-to-cell-openpyxl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Assuming you are using* `styleframe` *since the question is tagged with* [styleframe](/questions/tagged/styleframe))

You can use the [`apply_headers_style`](https://styleframe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styleframe.html?highlight=apply_headers_style#styleframe.StyleFrame.apply_headers_style) method with the `cols_to_style` argument:

```
from styleframe import StyleFrame, Styler

...
sf.apply_headers_style(Styler(bg_color='yellow'),
                       cols_to_style='sub col 2')
sf.to_excel('output.xlsx').save()
```

[image]

If you want the filters as well you can pass `row_to_add_filters=0` to [`to_excel`](https://styleframe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styleframe.html?highlight=to_excel#styleframe.StyleFrame.to_excel):

```
sf.to_excel('output.xlsx', row_to_add_filters=0).save()
```

[image]

Comment: Just to add a little clarity, `sf` in the answer is a `StyleFrame` object. You can initialize a StyleFrame object with an existing dataframe, among other options. For example, `sf = StyleFrame(df)`