# openpyxl set background color for cells

Tags: python, colors, background, openpyxl

I would like to fill in these boxes with a coloured background, as they are elements that are append on the excel file, I cannot define the number of the box...

[image: Excel]

Any ideas?

> ws.append([datumcleaned,tagesinfo,])

here his the code:

```py
# Writing on a EXCEL FILE
filename = f"{myPath}/Monatsplan {userfinder} {month} {year}.xlsx"
try:
    wb = load_workbook(filename)
    ws = wb.worksheets[0]  # select first worksheet
except FileNotFoundError:
    headers_row = ['Datum', 'Dienst','Funktion','Von','Bis','Schichtdauer','Bezahlte Zeit']
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    ws.append(headers_row)
wb.save(filename)
ws.append([datumcleaned,tagesinfo,])
wb.save(filename)
wb.close()
```

Comment: Use a pattern fill.

Answer (score 0):

your best bet is to iterate over existing columns with `.iter_cols()` and apply background color to the index number -1 of every column since the appended row is the last index:

```
for cols in ws.iter_cols():
if cols[-1].value: # need to check the cells have values.
                  # otherwise colors the entire row.
    cols[-1].fill = PatternFill(bgColor="FFC7CE", fill_type="solid")
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but how do I tell it to fill the appended row? 
So it is only created on rowone..
Is it possible to have the example with the code that i posted?

Thanks

Comment: I added an image for example

Comment: If you want to access the last item added to the column use '-1' index.

Comment: I do something wrong in entering the code, kindly could you give me the example with the code I put? Thank you

Comment: Note that `bgColor` might not work as expected: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50209914/1603480 for more details